# Add only last item in arraylist twice

Tags: java, android

I need to add all items in the arraylist

**Logcat:**

```
E/BUSINESS_STR: fuflfilled
E/itemsaArrayList: [com.model.CommonListItems@307c24ff, com.model.CommonListItems@307c24ff]
```

**Code:**

```
if(BUSINESS_STR != null){

    Log.e("BUSINESS_STR", "" + BUSINESS_STR);

    CommonListItems commonListItems = new CommonListItems();


    for(int i = 0; i <= 1 ; i++) {
        commonListItems.setName("My Business");
        commonListItems.setName("Search Business");

        commonListItems.setImage(String.valueOf(R.drawable.business_icon));
        commonListItems.setImage(String.valueOf(R.drawable.search_business_icon));

        itemsaArrayList.add(commonListItems);
    }

    tvTitle.setText("Business");
}
```

Finally it is adding the last item `"Search Business"` twice. I need to add `"My Business"` first and then `"Search Business"`.

Comment: Can you explain more ? I am not getting your point

Comment: @pcpriyanka arraylist adding last item twice inside the for loop.I am not getting My Business.

Comment: why you used `for(int i = 0; i <= 1 ; i++) {...}`

Comment: @pcpriyanka I need to get thse two values

Comment: you have to write out of loop as @krzosik said answer

Comment: You can manually add the last item at the end of the loop. `itemsArrayList.add(itemArrayList.get(itemArrayList.size()));`

Comment: @pcpriyanka   now also it is adding the last item Search Business twice.any suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove for loop:

```
commonListItems.setName("My Business");
commonListItems.setImage(String.valueOf(R.drawable.business_icon));
itemsaArrayList.add(commonListItems);

commonListItems = new CommonListItems();

commonListItems.setName("Search Business");
commonListItems.setImage(String.valueOf(R.drawable.search_business_icon));
itemsaArrayList.add(commonListItems);
```

Comment: now also it is adding the last item Search Business twice.any suggestion.

Comment: create a new CommonListItem before adding search business: commonListItems = new CommonListItems();

Comment: And remember to remove for loop

Answer (score 1):

add

```
commonListItems = new CommonListItems();
```

as first statement in **for** loop. Now your code will be like this

```
if(BUSINESS_STR != null){

Log.e("BUSINESS_STR", "" + BUSINESS_STR);

CommonListItems commonListItems;


for(int i = 0; i <= 1 ; i++) {
    commonListItems = new CommonListItems();
    if(i==0){
       commonListItems.setName("My Business" + i);
       commonListItems.setImage(String.valueOf(R.drawable.business_icon));
   } else {
      commonListItems.setName("Search Business" + i);
      commonListItems.setImage(String.valueOf(R.drawable.search_business_icon));
   }

    itemsaArrayList.add(commonListItems);
}

tvTitle.setText("Business");
}
```

Comment: @UserAgr you are not changing values for arraylist item inside for loop thats why you are able to see same item twice.

Comment: I have changed my answer

Comment: @UserAgr Thanks. Mark it as a right answer too (right tick).

Answer (score 0):

You add the same instance of `CommonListItems` in your list - twice.
Remove the for loop and create two objects of type `CommonListItems`.

```
CommonListItems commonListItem1 = new CommonListItems();
commonListItem1.setName("My Business");
commonListItem1.setImage(String.valueOf(R.drawable.business_icon)); 

CommonListItems commonListItem2 = new CommonListItems();
commonListItem2.setName("Search Business");
commonListItem2.setImage(String.valueOf(R.drawable.search_business_icon));

itemsaArrayList.add(commonListItem1);
itemsaArrayList.add(commonListItem2);
```